# Can't access device camera on Cordova/PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, phonegap, getusermedia

I'm trying to connect to device camera.
Everything works fine in browser, but not in Cordova.
No error is shown in console, nothing happens at all.
The result is just an empty video tag, with a large play icon on it.

Any reason why this is happening and how to fix it?

HTML/CSS/JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * data: blob: android-webview-video-poster: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline';">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", ready, false)
        function ready()
        {
            var video = document.getElementById('video');

            // Get access to the camera!
            if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
                // Not adding `{ audio: true }` since we only want video now
                navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
                    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                    video.play();
                });
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body id="body" class="wide-layout">
    <video id="video" width="640" height="480"></video>
</body>

</html>
```

Config.xml:

```
<platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />

        <config-file parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="true" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        </config-file>
    </platform>
```

Plugins:

```
cordova-plugin-android-permissions 1.0.0 "Permissions"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-media-capture 1.4.3 "Capture"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you see in the console output when you debug the app running on the device? You can see this by deploying the app with Visual Studio 2017 and the Apache Cordova tools, give it a try. The so-called browser platform is not enough for testing anything, you must debug on real devices.